# How to get the distance in pixels between two margins in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class = "container">
<p> class = "A"> One </p>
<p> class = "B"> Two </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.A{ margin-bottom: 40px;}
.B{margin-top: 10px;}
.container{height: 50px;}
```

I want to know how I can calculate to get the distance in pixels between **.A** and **.B**
Thank You

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8q8w.png)

Comment: what have you tried to solve that problem? And what was the problem with your approach?

Comment: @t.niese I have tried nothing but I read lots of posts and don't found anything to help me

Comment: @Laif I am just trying to get the required values by using simple math,  but don't have any idea how to get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, so the styles are likely not applying.

You are closing the `<p>` tags before you apply the classname, you are also placing spaces around the `=` in the classname declaration. Both of these things are invalid.

Your HTML should look like this, when properly formatted

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="A"> One </p>
  <p class="B"> Two </p>
</div>
```

---

As for the size, you are dealing with something called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

The margin between the two when this occurs will become equal to whichever margin was largest. In this case, 40px.

```css
p{
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.measurement{
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.A{ margin-bottom: 40px;}
.B{margin-top: 10px;}
.container{height: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="A"> One 
    <div class="measurement">40px</div>
  </p>
  <p class="B"> Two </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you verify that it is `50px` in css you have margin collapse.

Comment: @t.niese Ah, for me they did not collapse, but I see how that could be an issue

Comment: the container is itself 50px and the classes will take the full width of the container on margin?

Comment: @Pepichka check edit

Comment: @Laif How many pixels it collapse in my case?

Comment: 10 is smaller than 40, so the margin will become 40 between both

Comment: @Laif and make an edit to my post with correct formation I will approve it thanks

Comment: @Pepichka the original question shouldn't be changed to reflect the answer, the answer should just be accepted

Comment: @Laif so 40px is the correct distance between both A and B ?

Comment: @Pepichka Yes, I've edited my answer to prove it.

Comment: @Laif Thank You for the solution, I also updated the question and added an image in which everything is shown clearly, B is collaping out of the container.

Comment: @Pepichka the elements themselves have height, plus the default margin inherent in a `<p>` tag, so that would make sense why it is overflowing

Comment: @Laif Your answer is correct according to your logic of calculation but the my digital HTML book says this is not correct,  got this task from school to complete.

Comment: @Pepichka There's a lot of things that could be. The book could be out of date, there may be other styles and things you are missing, it might be wrong, i'm not sure what to tell you

Comment: @Laif I accepted Your answer because it seems right to me, if tomorrow they count my answer wrong I will be challenging them to prove why the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Pepichka What does the book claim the answer is?

Comment: @Laif 2.5rem.  which is 40 in pixels and I don't know it needs the answer in rem

Comment: @Pepichka what is supposed to be that size? the container? the container has a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

JS Solution if you need dynamic calculations on, for instance, window resize.

You can pass DOM elements into the function as well.

```
 const getDistance = () => {
   const containerWidth = document.querySelector("#container").getBoundingClientRect().width;
   const A_width = document.querySelector("#A").getBoundingClientRect().width;
   const B_width = document.querySelector("#B").getBoundingClientRect().width;

   return containerWidth - (A_width + B_width);
   
 }
```

Comment: Sir post a working snippet which I can run

Comment: @Pepichka so you are unable to plug the numbers in ?